# When uniquely divisible objects can be embedded into ind-torsion ones?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $A$ be an AB3 abelian category. We will say that an object $M$ of $A$ is uniquely divisible if for any integer $n\neq 0$ the endomorphism $nid_M$ is  invertible. We will say that $M'$ is ind-torsion if it belongs to the smallest Serre subcategory of $A$ that contains all torsion objects (that is, those $N\in A$ for which there exists $n\neq 0$ such that $nid_N=0$) and is closed with respect to $A$-coproducts.

My question is: which assumptions of $A$ are sufficient to ensure that there do not exist non-zero  monomorphisms from a uniquely divisible $M$ into an ind-torsion $A'$? This statement is obvious for abelian groups, but I do not know how to generalize it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your category $A$ is AB5, the answer is positive, because the ind-torsion objects are only the objects $X$ of $A$ such that the canonical map from the colimit $_\infty X$ of $_n X$ to $X$ is an isomorphism, where $_n X$ is the kernel of multiplication by $n$ on $X$ and the (filtered) colimit is taken over positive integers $n$ ordered by divisibility. (The only thing to check is stability under extensions of this class of objects; thanks to AB5 the proof is the same as for abelian groups.) If $M$ is such that $n.Id_M$ is a mono for each integer $n>0$ (it is true for any subobject of a uniquely divisible object), then $M\to\, _n X$ is always zero, so $M\to\,_\infty X$ is always zero because $A$ is AB5.

I guess that AB4 is not enough.

Comment: Sorry; after we dualize we will probably obtain an epimorphism from a uniquely divisible object and not a monomorphism; won't we?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me; I have corrected this.

Comment: Doesn't the map go in the wrong direction now? In the opposite category of abelian groups you have described a monomorphism from an ind-torsion object to a uniquely divisible one. However, $\mathbb{Q}$ is both ind-torsion in the opposite category of abelian groups *and* uniquely divisible, so $\text{id}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ works.

Comment: Sorry for this error and thanks for noticing this, I delete the remark for AB4, which requires more care.

Comment: The following should work for a counterexample in the opposite category of abelian groups: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a direct summand, so in particular a quotient, of a countable product of copies of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. I hope that now nothing is wrong with variances!

Comment: Yes, that works. In fact, in the opposite category of abelian groups, *every* object is ind-torsion.

Comment: I missed the end of your previous comment, sorry for that! Indeed the situation of the opposite category of abelian groups is very different from the one of the usual variance. Thanks!